Why does my client code close the connection after the first send call?
I'm trying to build a very simple socket example, where a client connects to a server, reads data from stdin and sends it to the server over a TCP loopback socket.
My problem: the first call to recv on the server works as expected, but the second call in a loop always returns 0, indicating that the client has closed the connection. The client still prompts me to enter input, but the server does not receive anything. However, I fail to understand how that would be possible, since the client only repeats the input and send in a loop.
client.cpp
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    if (argc != 2) {
        std::cerr << "Usage: " << argv[0] << " <port number>" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    addrinfo hints{.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP,
                   .ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM,
                   .ai_family = PF_INET};

    addrinfo* result;

    int getaddrresult = getaddrinfo("localhost", argv[1], &hints, &result);
    if (getaddrresult != 0) {
        std::cerr << "getaddrinfo failed: " << gai_strerror(getaddrresult) << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    if (result == nullptr) {
        std::cerr << "getaddrinfo returned nullptr" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    int sockFd = socket(result->ai_family, result->ai_socktype, result->ai_protocol);

    if (sockFd == -1) {
        std::cerr << "socket failed" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    int connectResult = connect(sockFd, result->ai_addr, result->ai_addrlen);

    if (connectResult == -1) {
        std::cerr << "connect failed" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    std::cout << "Connected to server" << std::endl;

    while (true) {
        std::string message;
        std::cout << "Please enter message: ";
        std::getline(std::cin, message);

        if (message == "exit") {
            break;
        }

        int sendResult = send(sockFd, message.c_str(), message.size(), 0);

        if (sendResult == -1) {
            perror("send failed");
            return 1;
        }

        std::cout << "Sent " << sendResult << " bytes" << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "Closing connection" << std::endl;
    close(sockFd);
    freeaddrinfo(result);


    return 0;
}

server.cpp
#include <netdb.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

pair<string, string> getHostAndPort(const sockaddr *addr) {
    char host[NI_MAXHOST];
    char port[NI_MAXSERV];
    int getnameinforesult = getnameinfo(addr, sizeof(addr->sa_len), host,
                                        NI_MAXHOST, port, NI_MAXSERV, 0);
    if (getnameinforesult != 0) {
        return {"<unknown>", "<unknown>"};
    }
    return {host, port};
}

int main() {
    addrinfo hints{.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP,
                   .ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM,
                   .ai_family = PF_INET};
    addrinfo *result;
    const char *port = "50069";
    int getaddrresult = getaddrinfo("localhost", port, &hints, &result);
    if (getaddrresult != 0) {
        cout << "getaddrinfo failed: " << gai_strerror(getaddrresult) << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    if (result == nullptr) {
        cout << "getaddrinfo returned nullptr" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    const auto [host, portString] = getHostAndPort(result->ai_addr);
    int sockFd =
        socket(result->ai_family, result->ai_socktype, result->ai_protocol);

    if (sockFd == -1) {
        perror("socket failed");
        return -1;
    }

    if (bind(sockFd, result->ai_addr, result->ai_addrlen) == -1) {
        perror("bind failed");
        return -1;
    }
    cout << "bound to port " << portString << endl;

    if (listen(sockFd, 10) == -1) {
        perror("listen failed");
        return -1;
    }

    cout << "listening for incoming connections on " << host << ":"
         << portString << endl;

    sockaddr_storage clientAddr;
    socklen_t clientAddrLen = sizeof(clientAddr);
    while (true) {
        int clientFd = accept(sockFd, (sockaddr *)&clientAddr, &clientAddrLen);
        if (clientFd == -1) {
            perror("accept failed");
            return -1;
        }
        const auto [clientHost, clientPort] =
            getHostAndPort((sockaddr *)&clientAddr);
        cout << "accepted connection from " << clientHost << ":" << clientPort
             << endl;

        std::vector<char> buffer(1024);
        int bytesReceived;
        while (true) {
            bytesReceived = recv(clientFd, buffer.data(), buffer.size(), 0);
            if (bytesReceived == -1) {
                perror("recv failed");
                return -1;
            } else if (bytesReceived > 0) {
                std::string receivedData(buffer.data(), bytesReceived);
                cout << "received " << bytesReceived << " bytes: <"
                     << receivedData << ">" << endl;
            } else if (bytesReceived == 0) {
                cout << "client closed connection" << endl;
                break;
            }
            buffer.clear();
        }

        close(clientFd);
        cout << "closed connection to " << clientHost << ":" << clientPort
             << endl;
    }
    close(sockFd);

    freeaddrinfo(result);
    return 0;
}



CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

project(server_client)

add_compile_options(-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Werror)

add_executable(server src/server.cpp)

add_executable(client src/client.cpp)

Expected behavior:
The second call to recv in the next iteration blocks until it receives data again.
Actual output
server:
./server
bound to port 50069
listening for incoming connections on localhost:50069
accepted connection from localhost:65036
received 15 bytes: <fshdjkfhkdjsfsd>
client closed connection
closed connection to localhost:65036
^C

client
./client 50069
Connected to server
Please enter message: fshdjkfhkdjsfsd
Sent 15 bytes
Please enter message: fhdjskfhksd
Sent 11 bytes
Please enter message: ^C


Can you provide a [mcve]?

I have linked the minimal example in the post.

Can you provide a [mcve] as text in your question, not behind a link to an external resource?

Sure, I can paste it in the question.

My compilers don't completely support C++23. I can't compile your code.My gcc doesn't find the header print and my clang doesn't find the headers format and print. I've even tried current Docker images with gcc or clang. If you could reduce the standard to 17 or 20, more people could debug your code.

Good point, I'll change it to a lower standard, didn't think that would be an issue.

If you removed just the println calls and the #include <format>, and #include <print>, that's all you need to reduce the standard to 17 or 20.

I've replaced the println calls and set the standard to 17 and included a CMakeLists

What did the serve print? What did the client print?

I've added the output now as well

I get server.cpp:15:60: error: ‘const struct sockaddr’ has no member named ‘sa_len’ and I can't find sa_len in the man page: https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sockaddr.3type.html I know that Linux isn't a real Unix, but both should be POSIX compliant. What Unix do you use? Do you have documentation of sockaddr with sa_len?

The key part of your server read loop is:
        std::vector<char> buffer(1024);
               :
        while (true) {
            bytesReceived = recv(clientFd, buffer.data(), buffer.size(), 0);
               :
            buffer.clear();
        }

So you have a buffer that you initialize as 1024 bytes, and then at the end of the loop, you resize it to 0 bytes (that is what .clear() does).  That means that the second call to recv has a size of 0, and so returns 0, which you then treat as an EOF.
Remove the buffer.clear(); and things should work.
Since the buffer has a fixed constant size, it might be better to use
std::array<char, 1024> buffer;


Thank you so much. I accidentally moved the vector declaration out of the loop and then one thing lead to another. So I've basically hit an edge case, where recv returned 0 which usually indicates a closed connection, but it actually returned 0 because my buffer was of size 0. Oh my
